# Transition of navbar back button not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

```
Ionic version:

[ ] 1.x 

[x] 2.x RC5

[x] bug report

[ ] feature request

[ ] support request
```

**Current behavior:**

There is no transition ocurring after pressing the navbar back button, or a custom "pop" button or the native hardware back button on the android phone.

It works with 'ionic serve' but not when 'ran as an apk'

**Expected behavior:**

It should make a transition back to the last page on the navcontroller stack.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Click on the navbar back button in 'native mode'

**Related code:**

```
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <button (click)="back()" ion-button icon-left clear small>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
    <div> Voltar</div>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
```

---

```
public back = (url) => this.navCtrl.pop();
```

Other information:

[image]

Zenfone 2

Ionic info: (run ionic info from a terminal/cmd prompt and paste output below):

> Your system information:
>
> ordova CLI: 6.4.0
>
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.5
>
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
>
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
>
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
>
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
>
> ios-sim version: Not installed
>
> OS: Windows 10
>
> Node Version: v7.4.0
>
> Xcode version: Not installed

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10097

Answer (score 0):

In the html  you are not passing any arguments to the back function but in your ts file, you are taking an argument called "url" for your back function.

```
//On a sidenote try declaring your function like below instead of assigning a public variable back to a function : 

back(){
    this.navCtrl.pop()
}
```